# Using order of an element to prove a congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have that $p=1$ mod $3$. Knowing there is an element $n$ with order $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$, how can I show that $(2n+1)^2=-3$ mod $p$. ($p$ is prime).
I'm not sure how to use that $n$ has order $3$ to prove it.

Comment: That last equation ($(2n + 1)^2 = -3$), is that modulo $p$?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation is $$ (2n+1)^{2} \equiv -3 $$ $$ 4n^{2} + 4n + 4 \equiv 0 $$ $$ 4(n^{2} + n + 1) \equiv 0,$$ which is equivalent to $$n^{2}+n+1 \equiv 0.$$ Since $n$ has order 3, it satisfies $n^{3}-1 \equiv 0$, or $(n-1)(n^{2}+n+1) \equiv 0$. Since $n \neq 1$ (even mod $p$), it must be a mod $p$ root of $n^{2}+n+1$ and the equation is satisfied.

From a Galois theory perspective, if an element of a field has order 3, its minimal polynomial is $n^{2}+n+1$, so it satisfies that polynomial.